# Отформатировать таблицу HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде, элементарно, можно использовать rowspan, но прописанные стили бордюра для td залезают под ячейку с ценой. Подскажите, как привести к такому виду таблицу, как на скришоте?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону псевдокласса [last-child](https://webref.ru/css/last-child)

Comment: tr{border-bottom:1px solid #000}
tr:last-child{border-bottom:none}
бордюры, так рисую, не понятно как применить по другому last-child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужный эффект (при корректной разметке) достигается всего за три шага.

- Устанавливаем верхнюю и нижнюю границу для таблицы.
- Для всех строк у первого столбца устанавливаем нижнюю границу.
- Для последней строки у первого столбца убираем нижнюю границу.

Ниже пример разметки и стилей для достижения нужного вам эффекта.

```css
table {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 400px;
}
td {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
td:first-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
td + td {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>очищение</td>
    <td rowspan="5">5000 руб</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>гоммаж (глубокое очищение)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>массаж</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>нанесение AHA-сыворотки</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>завершение (крем-база)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```